# what is the meaning of shadow variable in tensorflow and what is it used for?

Tags: tensorflow

I am reading the tensroflow document. In [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train/moving_averages) page, I have encounted a term shadow variable,i couldn't figure out what is the meaning of it and what is it used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says it in the document you linked:

> The apply() method adds shadow copies of trained variables and add ops
>   that maintain a moving average of the trained variables in their
>   shadow copies

Shadow Variables are *copies* of the main train variables that are used to mantain the moving average. The idea is that they *follow* the main Variable like a *Shadow*  ^_^